# CONVERT throw Error converting data type date to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a table `INTEG_LOG` which contains a date column `DATE_LOG`. From that date, I need to extract the date in the format `20171907` and the hour like `094225`.

In the first place I tried to get my date. For that I use this line:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE_LOG, 111), '/', '') AS LOG_DATE
FROM
    INTEG_LOG
```

It's not really clean but it's working fine.

I decided to do the same for the hour with this line:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATE_LOG, 108), ':', '') AS LOG_HOUR
FROM
    INTEG_LOG
```

But this SQL throws

> Error converting data type date to varchar

I even tried without the replace and I still get the same error.

I don't really get why the first convert with the style 111 is working fine but not the 108.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? And what **datatype** is that column `DATE_LOG` ?? You said it was a "date" column - but if it really were of datatype `DATE`, that wouldn't contain any time portion.....

Comment: For me - with SQL Server 2014 and a `DATETIME2(3)` (or even `DATETIME`) datatype column - this code works just fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i added the version of sql server. When I inspect my column, it's a date. I already tried those request with GETDATE() and it worked. And you were right, when i changed my column into datetime it worked. Thanks

Comment: @nebra How it can be a date 20171917? Month can't be more than 12 I guess.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко It's a typo, i wanted to say '20171907'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've got a table INTEG_LOG which contains a **date** column DATE_LOG

The error you've got is legitimate because the **date** type has no time component, so you cannot convert it to string using style 108

Try this

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(getdate() AS DATE), 108), ':', '')
```

and you'll get the same error.

So you should just select a constant like this:

```
select '000000' AS LOG_HOUR
```

or alternatively cast your date to datetime and you'll get the thame using your code:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), cast(DATE_LOG as datetime), 108), ':', '') AS LOG_HOUR
FROM
    INTEG_LOG
```